# Good way to serialize array in Java that is readable from Python?

Tags: java, python, database, arrays, serialization

I have some Java's serialized objects (arrays of doubles) in MySql database fields that I generated previously. Now I needed to read them from Python and I have just realized that it is probably not possible to do directly.

Then I tried to convert them to strings in java (simply comma delimited), and manually parse them from Python. But, it turned out that parsing from Python works painfully slow this way. Is there any better way for serializing arrays that is compatible between Java and Python?

---

Edit: Sorry, my parsing code was the problem, of course. I replaced it with this:

```
stringList = string.split(', ')
svdVector = [float(x) for x in stringList]
```

..and now it is almost instant for my case of 1000x1000 doubles. Although it still feels wrong to store doubles as strings instead of binary, but since it's easy to code and runs fast enough, it is fine.

Comment: Parsing comma-delimited strings in Python is quite fast, actually. You might get some mileage from posting your code and asking for help in speeding it up. My guess is that you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python comes with modules for CSV files, XML, and JSON, so one of those would likely do the trick quite well.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to try binary serialization, check out the built-in `struct` and `array` modules for help with interpreting the data in Python.